# How can I create a M365 Group with a specific Preferred Data Location (PDL) using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to programmatically create an M365 group with a Preferred Data Location that is different from the tenant default using the Graph API. I am trying to pass the PDL in via a PowerShell script, but when I add this command, I get a 403 Forbidden error of "InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException"

Has anyone successfully used the Graph API to create a Group (and eventually Team) in a non-default PDL?

Some technical background:

- The tenant is Geo-enabled, and users have default PDLs. Default location is US, trying to create the group in CAN
- Group creation is happening via a PS Script
- PS script is using AAD app permissions, and has appropriate Directory.readwrite.all permissions, etc.
- My script works perfectly in creating a group right I don't try to add the preferredDataLocation parameter. It only fails when I enable this specific parameter in the request body.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the property [preferredDataLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) can be set on the group while creating it or updating it through the REST API. Add this property in your request to the preferred data location for the group. Described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/multigeo-introduction)